# Glassfish server open source addition failed to install

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

i got the following error when i tried to install GlassFish Server glassfish-3.1.2.2-windows().exe

Executing command :C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4646 --instanceport 7070 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 domain1 
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat --user admin --passwordfile - create-domain --savelogin --checkports=false --adminport 4646 --instanceport 7070 --domainproperties=jms.port=7676:domain.jmxPort=8686:orb.listener.port=3700:http.ssl.port=8181:orb.ssl.port=3820:orb.mutualauth.port=3920 do  main1 The system cannot find the path specified.

print screen of error is following
[image]

Comment: I don't see the screenshot, please attach the error.

Comment: i have attached the error just above **print screen of error is following** line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem and it appears to be created by the batch files asadmin.bat and asenv.bat. The batch files read as follows (I've removed the REM statements and lines that didn't pertain to the problem:

**asadmin.bat in c:\glassfish3\glassfish\bin**

```
REM Always use JDK 1.6 or higher
REM Depends on Java from ..\config\asenv.bat

call "%~dp0..\config\asenv.bat" 
if "%AS_JAVA%x" == "x" goto UsePath
set JAVA="%AS_JAVA%\bin\java"
goto run
:UsePath
set JAVA=java
:run
%JAVA% -jar "%~dp0..\modules\admin-cli.jar" %*
```

**asenv.bat in c:\glassfish3\glassfish\conf**

```
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java
```

I could not figure out how to get Glassfish to just use the environment variable during install. I attempted to use the -j "(javapath)" argument, but this didn't solve the problem for me.

What worked, and I'm not proud of this solution, is to give Glassfish what it's looking for. If you put together the path its constructing above, you get C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\bin\java.exe. Since Java installs to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe, I simply copied the contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\ to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\ and Glassfish installed correctly.

If someone else has a better solution to this problem, PLEASE post it!

Full Disclosure:
Installing Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on Windows Server 2008, running on a VM.

---

**Update:** A co-worker of mine came up with a different solution that doesn't involve copying the contents of C:\Program Files(x86)\java\jre7.

During the Glassfish install, at the point where it's requesting a password for the admin account, edit the asenv.bat file and add the "jre7\" to the line I quoted above. This forces Glassfish to look in the proper folder.